# Get vector data from OpenStreetMap as MySQL database

Tags: mysql, algorithm, gps, openstreetmap, backtracking

Is it possible to get vector data from OpenStreetMaps as MySQL tables - for example as Points_of_routes(x,y,id), Nodes(point1,point2,id), Route_define(route_id,node,id), Route_info(name,level,id)...?

I want to use this database structure for searching shortest way from point A to point B using backtrack algorithm and UTM.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) tool does exactly what you want: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/index.php?title=Osmosis/Detailed_Usage